# Send data with POST method, android studio singleton

Tags: java, android, authentication, singleton

I'm creating an app that include a login form, I'm using a singleton class, jsonobject request and volley library. Can someone tell me how to get email and password from the edit text in order to send them in post method to the URL?

Here's the login.java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText email,password;
private Button login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    //ip azienda
    //final String url = "http://192.168.10.59/mygymapi/Login.php";
    //ip casa mia
    final String url = "http://192.168.56.1/mygymapi/Login.php";
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest

                    (Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Response: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
            MySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Singleton code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.LruCache;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;



public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
}
```

Comment: Bro.. You have get text of your views. And add as param in hashmap using volley.

Answer (score 3):

You can try on following code.

Code

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email,password;
    private Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        //ip azienda
        //final String url = "http://192.168.10.59/mygymapi/Login.php";
        //ip casa mia
        final String url = "http://192.168.56.1/mygymapi/Login.php";
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
                String Email = email.getText().toString();
                String Password = password.getText().toString();

                try{
                        params.put("user_mail", Email);
                        params.put("user_pass", Password);
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest

                        (Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                int errorcode = response.getInt("errorCode");
                                String errormessage = response.getString("errorMessage");
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                                String token = data.getString("token");
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Token: " + token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                MySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where I have to put this code? I've got a few syntax errors

Comment: You just have to put the code above `JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

}`

Comment: @SalvatoreMontagna I realized you posted those 3 pictures with error on other's answer comment. I have re-edit the code for your better understanding. Do you have the POST request body already or do you understand what is POST request body?

Comment: Ok I get what you mean. The params are: user_mail and user_pass. I've edited android studio code like:                                              
                    params.put("user_mail", Email);
                    params.put("user_pass", Password);

Comment: Sorry for upseting you, I do not know where to put POST Request Body.

Comment: @SalvatoreMontagna No. You no need to put the POST Request Body one. I just give you an example that your params first parameter need to follow the POST Request Body. I re-edit the answer since you provide the POST Request Body.

Comment: I do not know why it gives me always the same response. Like it doesn't get email and password values. Android monitor has a few errors

Comment: Of course. There, API's code: http://mygym2017.altervista.org/Screenshot__8_.png    ;      Toast response of my application which you can understand seeing the first image: http://mygym2017.altervista.org/Screenshot__9_.png

Comment: Postman is giving me everytime correct response, so the problem is in android studio.

Comment: Android monitor errors: http://mygym2017.altervista.org/Screenshot__10_.png

Comment: @SalvatoreMontagna Mind showing me some dummy output from your POSTMan?

Comment: @SalvatoreMontagna I have edit the code for output. Try it out and see if you able to retrieve the token back or not. [You can refer following link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

Comment: It returns me these error: http://mygym2017.altervista.org/screen1.png. I tried to put try and catch in this way, but it doesn't work: http://mygym2017.altervista.org/Screenshot__13_.png

Comment: help me please. I'm desperate

Comment: @SalvatoreMontagna Hi. May I know what is meaning of don't work? Like you not getting the token back on your toast?

Comment: Yes, it's like I don't click the button. I do not get any token

Comment: @SalvatoreMontagna Hi. You should be have to click on button on your apps to get token since your code have `login.setOnClickListener`. If you press the button then retrieve the token back, then this piece of code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to post data

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

And add request to the request queue

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: I've got three errors: 1. http://mygym2017.altervista.org/1.png ; 2. http://mygym2017.altervista.org/2.png  ;  3. http://mygym2017.altervista.org/3.png

Comment: @Salvatore follow below comment it gives exact solution to your problem.